# how to view a webpage in android app?

Tags: android

I have created a app, in it, that app opens browser to view a webpage,.

Please suggest a code for-
when I'll click on a button, a webpage should be open, without opening browser.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `WebView`. Name it myWebView in your Java:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.your_webview);
```

. Then, `myWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");` to load the URL you wish.

In your Manifest, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`